# Leetcode 2161: Partition array according to given pivot

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, integer, time-complexity

I'm currently solving LeetCode problem [2161. Partition Array According to Given Pivot](https://leetcode.com/problems/partition-array-according-to-given-pivot/description/):

> You are given a **0-indexed** integer array `nums` and an integer `pivot`. Rearrange `nums` such that the following conditions are satisfied:
>
> - Every element less than `pivot` appears before every element greater than `pivot`.
> - Every element equal to `pivot` appears in between the elements less than and greater than `pivot`.
> - The **relative order** of the elements less than `pivot` and the elements greater than `pivot` is maintained.
>
>   - More formally, consider every `pi`, `pj` where `pi` is the new position of the `ith` element and `pj` is the new position of the `jth` element. For elements less than `pivot`, if `i < j` and `nums[i] < pivot` and `nums[j] < pivot`, then `pi < pj`. Similarly for elements greater than `pivot`, if `i < j` and `nums[i] > pivot` and `nums[j] > pivot`, then `pi < pj`.
>
> Return `nums` *after the rearrangement*.
>
> **Example**:
>
> **Input:** `nums = [9,12,5,10,14,3,10]`, `pivot = 10`
> **Output:** `[9,5,3,10,10,12,14]`

#### My solution:

A solution with `O(n)` memory is trivial. I tried to come up with a `O(1)` memory solution and approached a similar to insertion sort way:

```
public int[] pivotArray(int[] nums, int pivot) {
    for(int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++){
        if(nums[i] < pivot){
            for(int j = i; j > 0 && nums[j - 1] >= pivot; j--){
                int tmp = nums[j];
                nums[j] = nums[j - 1];
                nums[j - 1] = tmp;
            }
        }
        if(nums[i] == pivot){
            for(int j = i; j > 0 && nums[j - 1] > pivot; j--){
                int tmp = nums[j];
                nums[j] = nums[j - 1];
                nums[j - 1] = tmp;
            }
        }
    }
    return nums;
}
```

The issue is the solution has `O(n^2)` time complexity. Is there an algorithm to solve this faster than `O(n^2)`? I'm not sure if `O(n)` time and `O(1)` space complexity is possible though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With a slight variation on [the answer of Matt Timmermans](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76945384/5459839) you could first remove the pivot values from the input array (packing the other values to the left side of it), then apply a O(log) divide-and-conquer algorithm to repeatedly merge two subarrays that are already partitioned by the pivot, rotating the center two partitions (of the four partitions). Then finally insert the removed pivot values back between the two partitions that remain.

To avoid consuming O(log) stack space, perform the divide-and-conquer algorithm in a bottom-up fashion (no recursion).

Here is an implementation:

```
class Solution {
    void sliceRotateLeft(int[] arr, int start, int end, int shift) {
        // Rotation in O(), where  is the size of the array slice
        int size = end - start;
        if (size <= 1) return;
        shift %= size;
        if (shift == 0) return;
        for (int count = 0, first = 0; count < size; first++, count++) {
            int j = first;
            int value = arr[start + j];
            for (int i = j + shift; i != first; j = i, i = (i + shift) % size) {
                arr[start + j] = arr[start + i];
                count++;
            }
            arr[start + j] = value; 
        }
    }

    int sliceFindPivotIndex(int[] arr, int start, int end, int pivot) {
        // Linear search. NB: binary search would be possible, 
        //                    but does not improve overall complexity.
        while (start < end && arr[start] < pivot) start++;
        return start;
    }

    public int[] pivotArray(int[] nums, int pivot) {
        // Phase 1: pack all non-pivot values to the left
        int len = 0; // Number of non-pivot values
        for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
            if (nums[i] != pivot) nums[len++] = nums[i];
        }
        // Phase 2: partition non-pivot values into less-than, greater-than
        // Use bottom up divide-and-conquer
        for (int size = 1; size < len; size *= 2) {
            // Merge two correctly partitioned chunks into one combined chunk
            for (int start = 0; start + size < len; start += size * 2) {
                // Get the offsets of the partitioned subarrays
                int mid = start + size;
                int end = Math.min(mid + size, len);
                int left = sliceFindPivotIndex(nums, start, mid, pivot);
                int right = sliceFindPivotIndex(nums, mid, end, pivot);
                sliceRotateLeft(nums, left, right, mid - left);
            }
        }
        // Phase 3: inject the pivot values
        int pivotFrequency = nums.length - len;
        int i;
        for (i = len - 1; i >= 0 && nums[i] > pivot; i--) {
            nums[i + pivotFrequency] = nums[i];
        }
        for (i++; pivotFrequency > 0; i++, pivotFrequency--) {
            nums[i] = pivot;
        }
        return nums;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can solve this recursively in O(n log n) time.

First make recursive calls to partition the lower and upper halves, so that you have your array ordered like `lphLPH`.  Then rotate from `p` to `L` to get `lLphPH`.  Then rotate the `hP` to get `lLpPhH`

Answer (score 0):

```
public static int[] pivotArray(int[] nums, int pivot) {
        int result[] = new int[nums.length];
        int index = 0, n = nums.length;
        
        // First loop: Iterate through the array to collect elements less than pivot
        // Time complexity: O(n)
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            if (nums[i] < pivot) {
                result[index++] = nums[i];
            }
        }
        
        // Second loop: Iterate through the array to collect elements equal to pivot
        // Time complexity: O(n)
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            if (nums[i] == pivot) {
                result[index++] = nums[i];
            }
        }
        
        // Third loop: Iterate through the array to collect elements greater than pivot
        // Time complexity: O(n)
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            if (nums[i] > pivot) {
                result[index++] = nums[i];
            }
        }
        
        // Combining the time complexities of the three loops: O(n) + O(n) + O(n) = 3 * O(n) = O(n)
        
        return result;
    }
```

You can view my submission on LeetCode at this link: https://leetcode.com/problems/partition-array-according-to-given-pivot/submissions/1027366000/

Comment: This does not satisfy OP's request of O(1) space and O(n) Time complexity. You are using O(n) space

Comment: Unfortunately the algorithm still uses `O(n)` extra space.

Comment: You are absolutely right, If you're aiming for O(1) space complexity and O(n) time complexity in a pivot algorithm, the traditional approach is to use the two-pointer technique for in-place partitioning.

Comment: @AshishSharma, the two pointer technique doesn't lead to a *stable* result (i.e. the third requirement -- on the relative order -- is not fulfilled. What you have given here is what the asker called *"A solution with O(n) memory is trivial."*. It's not an answer to their question.

Comment: Ok I got it, thanks for helping me, for making me stop thinking in the wrong direction.